# Difference between SAML and MSAL? Which one should be setup with VB codes?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml, azure-ad-msal

Currently I'm working on webapps and its VB code. I need to deploy it into Azure platform but I'm not sure about this 2 things. FYI, system that I developed don't have login page, which is based on current pc login username. So I retrieved current pc login username and check with my database whether current user allowed to use or not. When its in localhost, everything ok, I can retrieve username but when I deployed it to Azure it can't since I need to setup for Azure AD. But I'm a bit confused as my IT global ask me to do some codes to read from Azure AD. How to configure it with codes and also in Azure? Is there any difference between MSAL and SAML? Do I need to setup for both or should I just setup either one? I'm new in this so I don't know much of it. Hopefully someone can help me to solve it as I'm stuck for a month now. Thank you in advance.

P/S: My systems is in VBA codes, not in C# as I can see that many sample/example is in C# codes.

*Link with Azure AD and get user details like username/emails/etc once browse the webapps

Answer (score 3):

SAML is a protocol used for authentication. A more contemporary protocol is OpenId Connect.

[MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) is a library that helps integrate your application with Azure AD.

I'd suggest you start with the [Microsoft identity platform (Azure Active Directory for developers)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/) and get yourself familiar with how to integrate your application successfully with Azure AD.

Some of the samples provided on that page teach how to make calls to [Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.com), where you'd be able to get more details about the signed-in user.

Comment: Just to expand: MSAL is a client side library that supports OpenID Connect. Go with this. There are no Microsoft client side libraries that support SAML.

Comment: is there any sample with VB code? most of the samples are in C# language

Comment: sorry, if I need to have a Two Factor authentication on a POST request of login with the notifies of Microsoft Authenticator (example: my user puts username and password and click on Login, but to login he must approvate on his Microsoft Authenticator app), I need to send a push notification on his Microsoft Authenticator with Microsoft Graph?